# Составление JSONpath, массив в массиве

Tags: json, jsonpath

Доброе время суток, друзья! Мне требуется ваша помощь с казалось бы простым JSON.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать простую, правильную, удобную структуру JSON документа. Использоваться этот JSON будет для того, чтобы в дальнейшем вытягивать из него нужные данные с помощью **JSONpath**. То, как я вижу структуру этого JSON я приложил в скриншоте.

Далее опишу то, как пытался делать я, но столкнулся с трудностями.

```
{
  "interests": [
    "sport": ["hockey":{"keywords": "keyword 1"},"socker":{"keywords":"keyword 2"}],
    "music": ["rap":{"keywords": "keyword 1"},"rock":{"keywords":"keyword 2"}]
  ],
  "activity": null
}
```

Я не понимаю, почему этот JSON не валиден. Нельзя делать массив внутри массива? Мне видится структура максимально простой для JSONpath. Потому что дальше я буду делать рандомизацию, и к элементам массива я буду обращаться по формуле типа `$.interests[1]` и так далее, и должна будет выстроиться определённая цепочка.

Тыкнете пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся? Обязательно нужно добавлять всюду бесконечные `{} {} {}{{ }}}} {{} { }{}` , раздувая тем самым иерархию JSON'a? Хотелось бы как-то типа "краткость сестра таланта". Благодарю

[image: Желаемая структура]

Comment: "hockey" - имя "метода", в массиве нет имен. Вот так выглядит массив:```[{"keywords": "keyword 1"},{"keywords":"keyword 2"}]```, у вас же "объект": ```{"hockey":{"keywords": "keyword 1"},"socker":{"keywords":"keyword 2"}}``` (замените [] на {} и json станет валидным)

Comment: А это не повлияет на то, смогу ли я обращаться к элементам по их номеру?

Comment: повлияет, если нужно по номеру - то не должно быть имени, вам необходимо решить как вы к ним будете обращаться по имени или номеру, если по номеру - убирайте имя, иначе - меняйте скобки

Comment: Собсна главным различием между [] и {} является то, как мы потом сможем обращаться к тому или иному элементу: по имени или по номеру.
Я правильный вывод сделал?)

Comment: Если **очень** сильно упростить - да. Вот более подробно, если интересно https://habr.com/ru/post/554274/